# your query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function, how to fix error?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions

How do I correct this code to fix the error I'm receiving of "Your query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function"

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.ACCOUNT_NUM, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.BR_NUM, CUSTOMER.REG_NAME, ORDER.ORDER_TYPE, ORDER.COMP_DT, ORDER.ISSUE_DT, [ORDER]![ACCOUNT_NUM] & [ORDER]![ORDER_TYPE] AS [Key], INTO Final Output
FROM (ORDER INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON ORDER.ACCOUNT_NUM = CUSTOMER.ACCOUNT_NUM) 
WHERE (((CUSTOMER.INDQ)=0) AND ((CUSTOMER.PLAN_IND)=1))
GROUP BY CUSTOMER. ACCOUNT_NUM, CUSTOMER. CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.BR_NUM, CUSTOMER.REG_NAME, ORDER.ORDER_TYPE, ORDER.COMP_DT, ORDER.ISSUE_DT, 
HAVING (((ORDER.COMP_DT)=20210129));
```

Comment: `[ORDER]![ACCOUNT_NUM] & [ORDER]![ORDER_TYPE]` is not in the group by list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing key from the `GROUP BY`.  I would recommend a couple other changes:

- Move the `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` clause.
- Use table aliases.

You also have some extraneous commas.

So:

```
SELECT c.ACCOUNT_NUM, c.CUSTOMER_NAME, c.BR_NUM, c.REG_NAME, 
       o.ORDER_TYPE, o.COMP_DT, o.ISSUE_DT,
       o.[ACCOUNT_NUM] & o.[ORDER_TYPE] AS [Key]
INTO Final Output
FROM (ORDER as o INNER JOIN
      CUSTOMER as c
      ON o.ACCOUNT_NUM = c.ACCOUNT_NUM) 
WHERE c.INDQ = 0 AND c.PLAN_IND = 1 AND
      o.COMP_DT = 20210129
GROUP BY c.ACCOUNT_NUM, c.CUSTOMER_NAME, c.BR_NUM, c.REG_NAME, 
         o.ORDER_TYPE, o.COMP_DT, o.ISSUE_DT, 
         o.[ACCOUNT_NUM] & o.[ORDER_TYPE]
```